# Common headers for angular js service calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular interceptor concept to set headers for all $http calls .
It is generating on login.

But i am facing problem here , for downloading file concept

```
downloadfile : function( Id ,success, failure)
{
var url = 'url'+Id;
$http.get( url, {cache: false} )
.success( function( data )
{

    if(success){

        window.location.href = 'url'+Id;
    }
})
.error( function( data)
{
    //error(data);
});
},
```

it was working fine before we are implementing the security ,now i need to pass common headers for window.href also .

Please suggest

My interceptor

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
    return {
        request: function($config) {
            if( $rootScope.user.loginticket )
            {
                $config.headers['my-ticket'] = $rootScope.user.loginticket;
            }

            return $config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You mean you have a common base URL that you wish to prepend to all AJAX calls using `$http`?

Comment: I have set common headers for all $http ,  but in this case window.location.href = 'url'+Id;   it is not taking , because it is not a http call , but no idea ,weather i have to set explicitly for this \

Comment: What is the goal for the success call? To redirect? If so, use `$location`

Comment: Basically - on clilck of a link i am making a service call and in the client side downloading that file